# Setting HOME variable in RHEL6 system wide

Tags: environment-variables, rhel-6

Where does the HOME variable get set in RHEL6 (SL6.1)?

On one system all users get HOME set to /home/username/, i.e. with the trailing slash, which I don't want, so I need to remove it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That variable should be set from the corresponding field in `/etc/passwd`. You should clean that up in there.

```
# grep test /etc/passwd
test:x:1001:1001::/home/test/:/bin/bash
# su - test -c 'echo $HOME'
/home/test/
# vi /etc/passwd
# grep test /etc/passwd
test:x:1001:1001::/home/test:/bin/bash
# su - test -c 'echo $HOME'
/home/test
```

(You should probably use `usermod` to update `/etc/passwd` rather than editing it directly.)

Comment: Correct! As it happens, we had some users input correctly, and some not, which is why I didn't notice. Thanks!